# Use javascript async until to stop execution of library

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using libraries I didn't write and can't modify to do the following:

```
libx.on('something', function(x){
  liby.next_var(function(y,z){
    dance(x,y,z);
  })
})
```

Unfortunately, I don't want to dance all night.  I want to make it possible to stop the execution of dance when a user clicks a button.

I tried to do this with the async library's until function:

```
var async = require('async');
var dancing = true;

async.until(function(){
  return !dancing;
},function(cb){
  libx.on('something', function(x){
    liby.next_var(function(y,z){
      dance(x,y,z);
    })
  })
},function(){
  console.log("dance() will no longer be called");
});

$('#stop').on('click', function(){
  // want to stop libx and liby calls
  dancing = false;
});
```

Keeping in mind I can't modify the signature of the on method for libx, or the next_var method of liby, how can I control and stop the callbacks to these methods from firing?

Comment: This depends entirely on what the `dance()` function is doing and there is no way to know what your options are without seeing that.  If it's synchronous, you cannot stop it.  If it's asynchronous (which it probably is), then we need to see how it works to see what the options are.

Comment: I don't want to stop in the middle of `dance()`.  Instead, once the user has clicked on stop, I want to prevent the next call to `dance()` from occurring.

Comment: You can rewrite the function of dance: `save_dance = dance; dance = function(){};`;

Comment: @stdob: How would I then use the save_dance function?

Comment: @Dave if you need resume `dance` late?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `async.until` is fine, the issue is that you're registering an event handler so every time `'something'` happens, you're going to dance. (Sounds fun!)

In this case, you don't even need to use `async` :

```
libx.on('something', function (x) {
  liby.next_var(function (y, z) {
    dance(x, y, z);
  })
})

$('#stop').on('click', function () {
  libx.removeListener('something', function () {
    console.log("dance() will no longer be called");
  });
});
```

The event listener is registered immediately and then, when you click on `stop`, the listener is removed and you won't be dancing when `'something'` happens again.

---

Alright, with a better understanding of the problem at hand, you were actually really close to the solution.

```
var async = require('async');
var dancing = true;

function danceUntil (x, y, z) {
  async.until(function () {
    return !dancing;
  }, function (cb) {
    dance(x, y, z);
    cb();
  }, function () {
    console.log("dance() will no longer be called");
  });
}

libx.on('something', function (x) {
  liby.next_var(function (y, z) {
    danceUntil(x, y, z);
  })
})

$('#stop').on('click', function () {
  dancing = false;
});
```

Comment: I tried that.  Unfortunately, libx isn't an Event Emitter, but something that quacks similar to it.  removeListener doesn't work here.

Comment: Oh, then you need to figure out how to unregister `libx` events. async won't save you here unfortunately. Have you tried `.off`?

Comment: .off doesn't work.  It looks like .removeListener is being called, but it's not preventing liby from continually calling dance.  If you're curious, libx is kafka-node's producer.

Comment: I am not at all familiar with that library, but I glanced at the docs and it seems [pause](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#pause) or [close](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#close-force-cb) are what you're after? You could also use your `dancing` flag and wrap `dance` with `if (dancing)`

Comment: I can close the producer, but that doesn't prevent dance from being called over and over again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91997/discussion-between-dave-and-pier-luc-gendreau).